# TensorFlow conv2d slow compared to others

Tags: performance, tensorflow, convolution

I'm trying to use TF to do some filtering. I have 60 images of size 1740 x 2340 and a guassian filter of size 16 x 16. I ran a conv2d as

```
strides = [1,1,1,1]
data_ph = tf.constant(data,tf.float32)
filt_ph = tf.constant(filt,tf.float32)
data_format = 'NCHW'
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(data_ph,filt_ph,strides,'SAME',data_format=data_format)
```

where

```
data_ph = <tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=(60, 1, 1740, 2340) dtype=float32>
filt_ph = <tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=(16, 16, 1, 1) dtype=float32>
```

I tried to use place holders instead of constants and I also tried to use readers such as tf.FixedLengthRecordReader. I repeated the experiments few times per run. The first runs in 12 secs and the subsequents run in 4 secs using constants and 5 secs using place holders. The same experiment ran in mxnet takes always 1.6 secs and in matlab 1.5 secs. In all cases I'm placing the computation on the GPU, a 8 GB Quadro K5200. Is this expected (some posts mention TF being slower than other frameworks) or am I doing anything wrong?